# Fast and unique hash function for unique key

Tags: sql, hash, unique

I currently have two tables where compound values of both are necessary for uniqueness, e.g.
I have a table `t1` as follows:

```
id | name
---------
1  | test
```

and a table `t2`:

```
t1_id | key | value
-------------------
1     | k1  | test1
1     | k2  | test2
```

Now I want that is not possible to create new table rows, that have the combination of `name => test`, `k1 => test1` and `k2 => test2`, but e.g `name => test`, `k1 => test1` and `k2 => thisisatest` should be possible.

I wanted to solve this by creating a hash field in `t1` with an value of `name + each (key + value) pair`, for this I need a hashing function that has uniqueness when giving that much data.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that?  Just define a unique constraint on the table:

```
alter table t2 add constraint unq_t2_t1_id_key_value
    unique (t1_id, key, value);
```

Let the database enforce the data integrity.